# Changing an existing column conditional on two other column

Tags: python

I have a data set:

```
ID    Fv_year   HP_b_year    HP_e_year

1      2010       0            2012
2       0        2009          2011
3      2000       0            2008
4      2001       0             0
```

I want generate:

```
ID    Fv_year  HP_b_year      HP_e_year

1      2010     2010            2012
2       0       2009            2011
3      2000     2000            2008
4      2001      0               0
```

In word, when Fv_year >0 , HP_b_year =0 and HP_e_year>0 then I want to make HP_b_year = Fv_year, otherwise keep HP_b_year as it was before. I have used following cod:

```
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    if x == 0 and y>0 and z>0:
        return y
    else:
        return x

df['HP_b_year'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.HP_b_year, x.Fv_year, x.HP_e_year), axis=1)
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc` with conditions

```py
df.loc[(df['HP_e_year']>0) & (df['Fv_year'].ne(0)), ['HP_b_year']] = df['Fv_year'][(df['HP_e_year']>0) & (df['Fv_year'].ne(0))]
```

```
    ID  Fv_year HP_b_year   HP_e_year
0   1   2010    2010    2012
1   2   0       2009    2011
2   3   2000    2000    2008
3   4   2001    0       0
```